# Applet to copy current date+time as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM to clipboard?

Tags: windows, mysql, date-time

I sometimes need to type the current date + time in MySQL format, ie. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.

Before I write one myself, does someone know of a Windows applet that does this, so I could just double-click on it, and paste the clipboard elsewhere?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Turns out it was pretty easy to do in [Freebasic](http://www.freebasic.net/), although it's a console applet instead of a GUI applet:

```
#include "vbcompat.bi"
#include "windows.bi"

Sub ClearClipboard(hwnd As HWND = NULL)
    OpenClipboard(hWnd)
    EmptyClipboard()
    CloseClipboard()
End Sub

Sub WriteClipboard(Text As String, CPFormat As Integer = CF_TEXT, hWnd As HWND = NULL)        
    Var hGlobalClip = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_SHARE, Len(Text)+1)        
    OpenClipboard(hWnd)
    EmptyClipboard()
    Var lpMem = GlobalLock(hGlobalClip)
    CopyMemory(lpMem, StrPtr(Text), Len(text))
    GlobalUnlock(lpMem)
    SetClipboardData(CPFormat, hGlobalClip)
    CloseClipboard()
End Sub        

Dim a As Double = Now()
Dim CurrentDateTime as String

ClearClipboard()
CurrentDateTime = Format(a, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")
WriteClipboard(CurrentDateTime)
```

Comment: Answers belong in the answer box.

Comment: I always thought applet refereed to the java specification?  Maybe just me...

Answer (score 0):

I quickly made an HTA utility to do that named [GetMySQLDateTime](http://scottrhee.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/getmysqldatetime-tiny-utility-to-get.html) using VBScript. Feel free to use/modify/redistribute it for any purpose. As it's a HTA, you may directly modify the code using any text editor.

[image: Screenshot]

Usage: Just run it and the string will be on your clipboard. Click "Refresh" button to update it.